# How to get reports on ec2 instances using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to generate a daily report(using lambda) on what new instances are added/deleted and any configuration changes made on the instance so that it helps my team at the time of budgeting.

I used the describe_instance to get the launch time of the instance and i want to compare it with yesterday's date and if it matches then append the instance ID and some other information to a excel sheet, but I am completely new to lambda and python and not sure how to create the logic after getting the launch time

```
ec2info = defaultdict()
for instance in running_instances:
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if 'Name'in tag['Key']:
            name = tag['Value']
    #Add instance info to a dictionary         
    ec2info[instance.id] = {
       'Name': name,
       'Type': instance.instance_type,
       'State': instance.state['Name'],
       'Private IP': instance.private_ip_address,
       'Public IP': instance.public_ip_address,
       'Launch Time': instance.launch_time
    }

attributes = ['Name', 'Type', 'State', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Launch Time']
for instance_id, instance in ec2info.items():
    for key in attributes:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key, instance[key]))
        print("------")
```

This is the output i am getting, not sure how to proceed after this?

### Name: aecpns-lb02

### Type: m4.xlarge

### State: running

### Private IP: 172.26.29.132

### Public IP: None

Launch Time: 2019-03-22 19:46:16+00:00

Comment: Be aware that there are various AWS services in this space already that might help you, such as AWS Config, AWS CloudTrail, and Cost Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to collect and maintain this information yourself, you can take advantage of the **AWS Config** service.

From [What Is AWS Config?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html):

> **AWS Config** provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and **how they were configured in the past** so that you can see how the configurations and relationships **change over time**.